# Prove that a complete Euclidean Space always has a orthonormal basis.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

The key area I am getting stuck on here is that the complete Euclidean space need not be separable.

I believe if it were a separable space then a proof could be achieved by applying the Gram-Schmidt orthogonality procedure to an arbitrary set of vectors and extending it to a basis.

But how should I go about this proof now?

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I am able to prove that a Euclidean space (non-separable) does not need to have a orthonormal basis by using the orthogonal system spanning an infinite Hilbert space as a counter example.

So now why must a complete Euclidean Space have an orthonormal basis? I cannot think of a counter example but cannot think of how to prove this and I can find little resources online able to help lead me in the correct direction.

Comment: Wait, what is a complete Euclidean space for you? If you are talking about vectors being orthonormal then you have to have an inner product. In other words aren't you simply talking about a Hilbert space? Also every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis. The basis is countable if and only if the Hilbert space is separable.

Comment: $\ell_2$ Hilbert space does have an orthogonal basis (what is your counterexample??). In my definition, a base is at most countable, so any inner product space with a basis is separable. So separability is necessary.